# set css and js custom group in carabiner using codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, carabiner

friends
my problem is : my project is on codeigniter. when i refresh my page first html content loaded and after some seconds that pages js and css loaded. for that i tried carabiner.
**step 1: i downloaded carabiner**
**step 2: i added it to `app/third_party/carabiner/`**
**step 3: now i add group in `app/third_party/carabiner/config/carabiner.php`**
 like this-

```
$config['groups']['custom_js'] = array('js' => array(array('base_url();/assets/js/jquery.js','base_url();/assets/js/jquery.min.js', TRUE, FALSE)));
$this->carabiner->display('custom_js');/* for load that group */
$carabiner_config = array(
            'script_dir' => 'assets/scripts/', 
            'style_dir'  => 'assets/styles/',
            'cache_dir'  => 'assets/cache/',
            'base_uri'   => base_url(),
            'combine'    => TRUE,
            'dev'        => FALSE,
            'minify_js'  => TRUE,
            'minify_css' => TRUE
);
```

> i also set this array in `config/carabiner.php` but dont know what is
>   problem still showing error due to missing `jquery.min.js` and
>   `jquery.js` any suggestion ??

Answer (score 0):

You assign the base_url() like string. So replace above coding like this

```
$config['groups']['custom_js'] = array(

    'js' => array(

        array(base_url().'/assets/js/jquery.js', base_url().'/assets/js/jquery.min.js', TRUE, FALSE)    
    )

    );
```